# text-overflow: ellipsis cuts the double dots on German Ö Ä Ü

Tags: html, css

i cut a text which is longer than my container (div) in my HTML with an text-overflow: ellipsis according to that i also set overflow: hidden to see dots if the text is longer as the width of the container.

This functionality is working perfectly but, the german 'Ö, Ä, Ü' (referenced, because it has been noticed on this characters) missing the dots on top if the line-height is lower than the height of the dots.

Assume that i cant increase the line-height. When i do this, its working. But is there a chance to have the same behavior without ellipsis only for the x - axes?

```css
    .box {
        width: 100px;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
    
    .font {
      font-family: UniversNextMedium;
      color: #3c3c3c;
      text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #FFFFFF;
      font-size: 21px;
      line-height: 15px;
    }
```

```html
    
    <div class="box font">
        hellowÖrldtheonlyworldwehave
    </div>
```

Here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/an256zu1/

Comment: The umlaute are being cut off by `.box { overflow: hidden; } `. But you need to property set like this as written at mdn: [`This CSS property doesn't force an overflow to occur; to do so and make text-overflow to be applied, the author must apply some additional properties on the element, like setting overflow to hidden.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow). So you will have to set a height (bad idea) or indeed just change the `line-height.`

Comment: I think you left out one important detail that's necessary to find a solution: Why can't you increase line-height?

Comment: Its an requirement by design, sounds stupid but it is like that! I know its stupid!

Answer (score 3):

Use `line-height:21px` similar to font-size.

Demo:   http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/an256zu1/1/

If you remove `overflow`, then ellipsis will not work. If use something else i.e. `margin or padding` then the layout may break.

Or you may also decrease the `font-size`. That will also solve your problem without breaking the layout

Answer (score 0):

Use  **padding-top:3px;** it works.

```css
.box {
    width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    padding-top:3px;
    border:1px solid
}

.font {
  font-family: UniversNextMedium;
  color: #3c3c3c;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 21px;
  line-height: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box font">
    hellowÖrldtheonlyworldwehave
</div>
```

Comment: May be yes  if you want to run out from padding then reduce font-size or increase line-height but if you increase line height the same your input box will grow so instead of using line-height use padding.

Comment: that i know but if he want font size 21 then you have increase  inline-height or padding @josef

Comment: @KevalBhatt sorry, removed my comment but too late - the problem with the padding is that letters extending below the baseline are still chopped off It is also likely to cause the same issues the increased line-height causes, but worth a try I guess, since the context is not very clear.

Answer (score 0):

You could use combination of margin and padding to fix the issue and preserve text position in layout. For example:

```css
    .box {
        width: 100px;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
    
    .font {
      font-family: UniversNextMedium;
      color: #3c3c3c;
      text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #FFFFFF;
      font-size: 21px;
      line-height: 15px;
      margin-top:-5px;
      padding-top:5px;
    }
```

```html
    
    <div class="box font">
        hellowÖrldtheonlyworldwehave
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the combination of the `line-height: 15px;` and `overflow: hidden;`. I would recommend to set a proper *line height*, `1.4` for example:

From the [article: line-height](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/l/line-height/):

> The recommended method for defining line height is using a number value, referred to as a "unitless" line height.

```css
.box {
    width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.font {
  font-family: UniversNextMedium;
  color: #3c3c3c;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 21px;
  line-height: 1.4;
}
```

```html
<div class="box font">
    hellowÖrldtheonlyworldwehave
</div>
```